# Custom wait condition in boto3 for efs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-efs

boto3 provides default **waiters** for some services like EC2, S3, etc. This is not provided by default for all services. Now, I've a case where an EFS volume is created and the lifecycle policy is added to the file system. The EFS creation takes some time and the lifecycle policy isn't in the required efs state. i.e., efs created.

How to wait for EFS to be created in a python boto3 code, so that policies can be added?

Comment: Just request the status in a loop until it's the desired state and then break the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a waiter doesn't exist for this, but you can create your own customer waiters like this:

```
import boto3
from botocore.waiter import WaiterModel
from botocore.waiter import create_waiter_with_client

client = boto3.client('efs')
waiter_name = "LifeCycleCompleted"
waiter_config = {
    "version": 2,
    "waiters": {
        "LifeCycleCompleted": {
            "operation": "DescribeLifecycleConfiguration",
            "delay": 60, # Number of seconds to delay
            "maxAttempts": 5, # Max attempts before failure
            "acceptors": [
                {
                    "matcher": "path",
                    "expected": lifecycle_policy,
                    "argument": "length(LifecyclePolicies[]) > `0`",
                    "state": "success"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
waiter_model = WaiterModel(waiter_config)
efs_lifecycle_waiter = create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, waiter_model, client)

efs_lifecycle_waiter.wait(FileSystemId='MyFileSystemId')
```

Comment: what is lifecycle_policy?

Answer (score 0):

Or Use something simpler as mentioned by @jordanm

```
import time
import boto3

efs_client = boto3.client('efs')

filesystem_status=""
while filesystem_status != "available":
    response = efs_client.describe_file_systems(
            FileSystemId=file_system_id,
            )
    filesystem_status=response["FileSystems"][0]["LifeCycleState"]
    print(f"{file_system_id} {filesystem_status} .... waiting")
    time.sleep(20)
```